# Cannot set min-height on v-carousel

Tags: css, vue.js, height, vuetify.js, carousel

I have a header pic which is made up of a Vuetify carousel.
The section container for the carousel is 100vh and the v-carousel element height is set to be 100%.
I would expect that setting a min-height of 300px on the section element would prevent the carousel pic from having a height smaller than 300px. Instead, while decreasing the screen height, I notice a line marking the min-height but the pic inside becomes smaller as I reduce the height of the screen. Below there is my code, can someone suggest what I am doing wrong? I see from the inspection tool that the v-carousel-item is a div with a background-image and I wonder if this affects somehow my code.

```
<template>
  <div class="home router-view">
      <section style="height:100vh;
       background-size:cover;
       background-attachment:fixed;
       background-position:center;
       position:relative;
       max-height:1300px; 
       min-height: 400px">
        <v-carousel
          cycle
          hide-controls
          hide-delimiters
          style="position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;height:100%"
        >
          <v-carousel-item 
            :src="require('@/assets/images/picture.jpg')"
          >
          </v-carousel-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your styling. Are you trying to make the  cover the whole page (100vh), all the time? Then you don't need min-height or anything.

Anyways, try adding **min-height:100%** inside v-carousel's styling to force height.

If it doesn't work, please see v-carousel's props and try add height="100%" natively provided by vuetify.

see: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-carousel/#props

If you provided a reproduction, codepen etc. your problem would be much clearer to understand.

Please let me know if it works!

Comment: It still doesn't work. The v-carousel-item doesn't work according to the min-height...

Comment: It seems like you're not looking for help but just whining that it does not work. You didn't further clarify your problem at all, so I have no additional information to work through and help you.
Only other thing I can say is you can try putting !important tag after min-height property of the component, or any other property that you think should change the height. Vuetify is sometimes stubborn about receiving custom styles.